# Linear relaxation infeasible in python using pulp, but still get an objective value

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I have an optimization problem using pulp in Python. I want to find the optimal allocation of a battery connected to a building that produces electricity using solar panels, but also has energy consumption. In addition, the battery is allowed to sell electricity back to the grid. The code I have until now is this:
Below, the decision variables in use are: SOC (the battery's state of charge or electricity in the battery), E_import which is imported electricity to satisfy the consumption, E_export which is exported excess electricity back to the grid

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_excel("1 (KWh & dayahead).xlsx", sheet_name="KWh prod")

# getting the values from the excel sheet
E_Consum = df.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()
timeperiods = df.iloc[:, 1].values.tolist()
C_elspot = df.iloc[:, 2].values.tolist()
FCR_price = df.iloc[:, 3].values.tolist()
PV_prod = df.iloc[:, 4].values.tolist()
month_nr = df.iloc[:, 5].values.tolist()
days = df.iloc[:, 6].values.tolist()

# checking that we get the right values
print(E_Consum[:5])

# Getting the cost for the effect link
day_max_kw = (df['KWh consumption'] - df['Production']).groupby([df['Month'], df['Day']]).max()
monthly_max = day_max_kw.groupby('Month').nlargest(1)
group1 = [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]
group2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
monthly_max.loc[group1] *= 75
monthly_max.loc[group2] *= 32
print(monthly_max)
sum_avg_mon = sum(monthly_max)

# Getting the electric cost of the building
for t in range(len(timeperiods)):
    df['sun_cost_original'] = (df['KWh consumption'] - df['Production']) * ((0.1416 if df.loc[t, 'Month'] in [1, 2, 3]
                                                                            else 0.2084) + df['DayAhead-price'])
df['cum_sum_orig_sun_cost'] = df['sun_cost_original'].cumsum()
print(df['cum_sum_orig_sun_cost'].iloc[-1])
print("Sum electricity cost before battery:", df['cum_sum_orig_sun_cost'].iloc[-1] + sum_avg_mon)

# Getting the numbers where PV_prod is larger than E_consum
selected_rows = df[df['Production'] > df['KWh consumption']]
# Print the row numbers
print(selected_rows.index.tolist())

# Creating optimization problem
problem = pulp.LpProblem("Minimization problem", pulp.LpMinimize)
# Defining the length of the optimization
num_periods = len(timeperiods)

# Defining boundaries
SOC_max = 1000
SOC_init = 100
SOC_min = 0.1
FCR_max = 1000
L_efficiency = 1
Charge_discharge_rate = 1


# adding decision variables
E_import = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("E_import", range(num_periods), lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
E_export = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("E_export", range(num_periods), lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
SOC = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("SOC", range(num_periods + 1), lowBound=SOC_min, upBound=SOC_max)
FCR_p = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("FCR_p", range(num_periods), lowBound=-FCR_max, upBound=FCR_max)
x_import = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("phi_import", range(num_periods), cat=pulp.LpBinary)
x_export = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("phi_export", range(num_periods), cat=pulp.LpBinary)
x_FCR = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("phi_FCR", range(num_periods), cat=pulp.LpBinary)
p = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("peak", range(12), lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)

# adding the E_import and E_export to df
df["E_import"] = [E_import[t] for t in range(num_periods)]
df["E_export"] = [E_export[t] for t in range(num_periods)]

# Adding the effect link cost
for m in range(12):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i, 'Month'] == m:
            if m in [0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11]:
                problem += p[m] >= 75 * E_import[i]
            else:
                problem += p[m] >= 32 * E_import[i]

# Model 3 and model 4: only FFR
obj_model_3 = pulp.lpSum((C_elspot[t] + 0.1416 if df.loc[t, 'Month'] in [1, 2, 3] else C_elspot[t] + 0.2084) * E_import[t]
                         - C_elspot[t] * E_export[t] * L_efficiency
                         for t in range(num_periods))
for m in range(12):
    obj_model_3 += pulp.lpSum(p[m])

# Updating constraints
for t in range(num_periods):
    # Battery constraint about charging/discharging
    problem += SOC[t] - SOC_max <= 0
    if t == 0:
        problem += SOC_init - SOC_max <= 0
    else:
        problem += SOC[t - 1] - SOC_max <= 0
    # left this out
    #if t == 0:
     #   problem += PV_prod[t] + SOC_init + E_import[t] == E_Consum[t] - E_export[t]
    #else:
     #   problem += PV_prod[t] + (SOC[t]-SOC[t-1]) + E_import[t] == E_Consum[t] - E_export[t]
    # must keep for the balance to be satisfied
    if t == 0:
        problem += SOC[t] == SOC_init + (PV_prod[t] - E_Consum[t]) + (E_import[t] - E_export[t])
    else:
        problem += SOC[t] == SOC[t-1] + (PV_prod[t] - E_Consum[t]) + (E_import[t] - E_export[t])
    # constraint for activating the SOC
    excess_electricity = PV_prod[t] + E_import[t] - E_Consum[t] - E_export[t]
    if t == 0:
        problem += SOC[t] - SOC_init + Charge_discharge_rate * SOC_max <= excess_electricity
    else:
        problem += SOC[t] - SOC[t-1] + Charge_discharge_rate * SOC_max <= excess_electricity
    deficit_electricity = E_Consum[t] - PV_prod[t] - E_import[t] - E_export[t]
    if t == 0:
        problem += SOC[t] - SOC_init - SOC_max * Charge_discharge_rate >= -deficit_electricity
    else:
        problem += SOC[t] - SOC[t-1] - SOC_max * Charge_discharge_rate >= -deficit_electricity

problem.setObjective(obj_model_3)
problem.solve()
```

When I try to solve the problem, the solver is quite quick to tell me that the problem is unfeasible, giving me the message: Result - linear relaxation infeasible. However, I am still presented with a number. Leaving me puzzled if the solver finds an objective value that is optimal, but it gets indecisive due to multiple optimal objective values. Or if it simply is an infeasible problem, but the soler finds an optimal solution (but is infeasible).

I have tried leaving out some of the constraints and adding some.
After leaving out the constraints under the "left this out", i received a lower value than before, but both times the problem is supposedly infeasible.
If i left the "balance" constraints out, then I get a wrong answer. And the "activating the SOC"-part is necessary for the battery to actually store excess energy.

the code i get is: primal infeasible - objective value 1 500 000 (approximately)

Comment: When the infeasibility is detected in the LP (during Simplex), it can report the solution of the last iteration. If the infeasibility is detected in the presolve, solvers typically don't give back any solution. Advice: Always check the status.

Answer (score 0):

When the solver detects the problem is infeasible, it returns the solution found on the last iteration it computed. Here's a simple example:

```py
import pulp

prob = pulp.LpProblem('Example', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
x = pulp.LpVariable('x', lowBound=0, upBound=10, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
y = pulp.LpVariable('y', lowBound=0, upBound=10, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
z = pulp.LpVariable('z', lowBound=0, upBound=10, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

prob += pulp.lpSum([x, y, z]) >= 20
prob += x + y <= 10
prob += y + z <= 10
prob += x + z <= 10

prob.setObjective(pulp.lpSum([x, y, z]))
prob.solve()

lpvars = {lpvar.name: lpvar.value() for lpvar in prob.variables()}

print(f"{' Objective Value ':=^60}")
print(f"Status: {pulp.LpStatus[prob.status]}")
print(f"Objective: {prob.objective.value()}")
print(f"{' Variables Values ':=^60}")
for name, value in lpvars.items():
    print(f"{name}: {value}")

print(f"{' Problem Constraints ':=^60}")
for lpname, lpcons in prob.constraints.items():
    c = _c = lpcons.__str__().replace('*', ' * ')
    for name, value in lpvars.items():
        c = c.replace(name, str(value))
    res = eval(c)
    print(f"{lpname}: {_c} -> {c} -> {res}")
# Prints:
#
# ===================== Objective Value ======================
# Status: Infeasible
# Objective: 15.0
# ===================== Variables Values =====================
# x: 5.0
# y: 5.0
# z: 5.0
# =================== Problem Constraints ====================
# _C1: x + y + z >= 20 -> 5.0 + 5.0 + 5.0 >= 20 -> False
# _C2: x + y <= 10 -> 5.0 + 5.0 <= 10 -> True
# _C3: y + z <= 10 -> 5.0 + 5.0 <= 10 -> True
# _C4: x + z <= 10 -> 5.0 + 5.0 <= 10 -> True
```

The example above is infeasible, because the first constraint (`x + y + z >= 20`) forces the sum of all variables to be greater than or equal to 20, but the second, third and fourth constraints restrict all variables in such a way that their sum can't be greater than 15.

### NOTE: Relaxing Infeasible Problems

For large problems, it can be particularly challenging to identify the parts that are making your problem infeasible manually. For such cases, one way to analyze the problem is to "relax" it.

I've created the following function that can be used to relax infeasible problems and identify a set of constraints that is making your optimization problem become infeasible. Here's the function:

```py
import pulp
from typing import Tuple


def relax_problem(infeasible_model: pulp.LpProblem, **solver_kwargs) -> Tuple[pulp.LpProblem, set]:
    """Relax an infeasible LP problem and identify infeasible constraints.

    The function checks if the model is unsolved or not infeasible and tries to
    solve or print an error message accordingly. It then initializes an empty
    set to store infeasible constraints and iteratively deactivates each
    constraint to check the feasibility of the model.

    Parameters
    ----------
    infeasible_model : pulp.LpProblem
        The infeasible linear programming problem to be relaxed.
    **solver_kwargs : dict
        Keyword arguments for the solver of the linear programming problem.

    Returns
    -------
    pulp.LpProblem
        The relaxed linear programming problem.
    set
        The set of infeasible constraints.

    Other Parameters
    ----------------
    solver : pulp solver, optional
        The solver to use for the linear programming problem. 
        By default, the CBC (COIN-OR Branch and Cut) solver provided by PuLP is used.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If the model is not infeasible.

    Examples
    --------
    Demonstration of function usage with dummy data.

    >>> from pulp import LpProblem, LpMaximize
    >>> prob = LpProblem("Test Problem", LpMaximize)
    >>> relax_problem(prob)
    """
    solver = solver_kwargs.pop('solver', pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(**solver_kwargs))

    # Check if the model is unsolved. If it's unsolved, execute the `solve`
    # method to solve the model
    if infeasible_model.status == pulp.constants.LpStatusNotSolved:
        infeasible_model.solve(solver)

    # Check if the model is infeasible
    if infeasible_model.status != pulp.constants.LpStatusInfeasible:
        print(
            "The model is not infeasible. "
            f"Model status: {pulp.LpStatus[infeasible_model.status]}."
        )
        return infeasible_model, set()

    # Initialize an empty set to store the IIS
    infeasible_constraints = set()

    # Create a new LP problem to store the modified version of the original problem
    modified_model = pulp.LpProblem("modified_model", sense=infeasible_model.sense)
    modified_model.addVariables(infeasible_model.variables())
    modified_model.setObjective(infeasible_model.objective)

    # Add lower and upper bound hard limits to the new problem for each variable
    # These constraints will serve as safety nets in case the original variable
    # was unconstrained
    variables = modified_model.variables()
    for index, variable in enumerate(variables):
        modified_model.addConstraint(variable >= -100_000)
        modified_model.addConstraint(variable <= 100_000)
        modified_model._variables[index] = variable

    # Iterate over each constraint in the original problem
    # Deactivate each constraint and check if the problem is still infeasible
    # If the problem is still infeasible, add the constraint to the IIS set
    # Otherwise, activate the constraint and move on to the next one
    for constraint_name, constraint in infeasible_model.constraints.items():
        modified_model.addConstraint(constraint, name=constraint_name)
        status = modified_model.solve(solver)
        if status == pulp.constants.LpStatusInfeasible:
            infeasible_constraints.add(constraint_name)
            modified_model.constraints.pop(constraint_name)
    return modified_model, infeasible_constraints
```

Running the `relax_problem` function in our infeasible example problem:

```py
relaxed_prob, infeasible_constraints = relax_problem(prob)
relaxed_prob.solve()
lpvars = {lpvar.name: lpvar.value() for lpvar in relaxed_prob.variables()}

print(f"{' Objective Value ':=^60}")
print(f"Status: {pulp.LpStatus[relaxed_prob.status]}")
print(f"Objective: {relaxed_prob.objective.value()}")
print(f"{' Variables Values ':=^60}")
for name, value in lpvars.items():
    print(f"{name}: {value}")

print(f"{' Problem Constraints ':=^60}")
for lpname, lpcons in relaxed_prob.constraints.items():
    c = _c = lpcons.__str__().replace('*', ' * ')
    for name, value in lpvars.items():
        c = c.replace(name, str(value))
    res = eval(c)
    print(f"{lpname}: {_c} -> {c} -> {res}")
# Prints:
#
# ===================== Objective Value ======================
# Status: Optimal
# Objective: 20.0
# ===================== Variables Values =====================
# x: 10.0
# y: 0.0
# z: 10.0
# =================== Problem Constraints ====================
# _C1: x >= -100000 -> 10.0 >= -100000 -> True
# _C2: x <= 100000 -> 10.0 <= 100000 -> True
# _C3: y >= -100000 -> 0.0 >= -100000 -> True
# _C4: y <= 100000 -> 0.0 <= 100000 -> True
# _C5: z >= -100000 -> 10.0 >= -100000 -> True
# _C6: z <= 100000 -> 10.0 <= 100000 -> True
# C1: x + y + z >= 20 -> 10.0 + 0.0 + 10.0 >= 20 -> True
# C2: x + y <= 10 -> 10.0 + 0.0 <= 10 -> True
# C3: y + z <= 10 -> 0.0 + 10.0 <= 10 -> True
```

In the above example, the function removed the constraint `C4: x + z <= 10`, thus making the problem feasible.